Windows service exception for reference dll code
I have a .NET Framework Windows Service application that uses reference DLLs to fetch data from a device. I’ve created a Windows Setup Project to install the service. The setup builds successfully, and the service installs and runs as expected.
As I already added one of referenced dll as reference in my application.
However, when I attempt to attach the debugger to the running service from Visual Studio, I encounter below exception
System.TypeInitializationException HResult=0x80131534 Message=The type of initializer for 'referenced dll' threw an exception.
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
I want the solution for the mentioned exception
